# Triggers handling and visibility (GAS) - best way to manage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have some Google Apps script code that uses triggers. Sometimes I delete old ones and add new ones.

The code is standalone, so the triggers are handled from the code editor (not with the button or menu on the sheet).

**The variants to setup the triggers:**

1) I have to ask a client to run the function to setup and reset the code, but it's not ok for him to do that.

2) I set up and reset all triggers under my account. But I might not work with this client forever.

What's the best to handle, have control over triggers and not bother the client?

What do you do?

Comment: Just submit a private add on  or share your code with client. Given the specificity of code for a particular purpose/project, it'll be rare for someone to steal and use it.

Comment: Get a business account and create a team drive and let the client join your team drive.  Build and deploy the script from the team drive.

Comment: Thanks. The clients wants to keep it on his Drive and he wants to hide the code from others) addons are confusing to me, I haven't find any simple explanations how to make them so far. Maybe web app?